# Cannot load local resource

Tags: apache, java, tomcat

In spring project, I am generating some pdf file automatically in my application and storing it in $CATALINA_BASE in tomcat server. The path is :

```
D:\Project_Local\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\happyweb\images\User.pdf
```

I have given one hyperlink on webpage to access this file. But when I click on that link it is giving error in Chrome console as below:

```
 Not allowed to load local resource:D:\Project_Local\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\happyweb\images\User.pdf
```

What is the problem and how so resolve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **I have given one hyperlink on webpage to access this file.**

When you provide the local path to a file in your webpages, as covered [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Web_pages), you're making the assumption that the file exists on the client's computer or device, not on your server.

Instead of using a local file path in your hyperlink like:

`D:\Project_Local\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\happyweb\images\User.pdf`

you should store the file in a directory that's served by your web server, and then use a URL to the file that includes your hostname, like:

`http://myserver.com/happyweb/images/User.pdf`

If you do intend to serve a file locally (i.e., on the same computer), then you should use the [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). On Windows, that would look like:

`file:///d:/path/to/User.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer worked for me. I am just trying to be more clear in my answer.

```
/(ProjectName) = D:/Project_Local/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ProjectName
```

So, create a folder and add all files or folders under the project title, say the folder is `/ProjectName/src/main/webapp/resources`.

Then, you need to use the following to load the file from the HTML page as follows:

```
<a href="/ProjectName/src/main/webapp/resources/filename">Click</a>
```